# How to create a resizable bordercontainer with 8 dots in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I would like to have a bordercontainer in Flex, that the user can resize on his own with 8 dots in the top left, top, top right, left, right, bottom left, bottom and bottom right (like MS Paint etc.)

Does Flex have a default solution for this, or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: It's not really necessary anymore, I've fixed it with a slider that resizes the bordercontainer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is [ObjectHandles](http://rogue-development.com/objectHandles.html).

Use the v1 of the plugin and you should be good to go.